# How to get the day of year in a batch file

Tags: windows, date, batch-file

How can I get the day of year from the current date in a Windows batch file?

I have tried

```
SET /A dayofyear=(%Date:~0,2%*30.5)+%Date:~3,2%
```

But it does not work with leap years, and it is always off by a few days. I would not like to use any third-party executables.

Comment: Are you talking about the Julian date? If so, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210997/dos-date-math

Comment: Yes. That answer works for me. Thanks a lot. @Ghost

Comment: Ghost's comment should be promoted to an answer, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the Julian Day Number, you may use the method posted in [my accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210997/dos-date-math/11213142#11213142) given at previous link. However, the "day of year" is just a number between 1 and 365 (366 for leap years). The Batch file below correctly calculate it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A i=0, sum=0
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set /A accum[!i!]=sum, sum+=%%a
)

set /A month=1%Date:~0,2%-100, day=1%Date:~3,2%-100, yearMOD4=%Date:~6,4% %% 4
set /A dayOfYear=!accum[%month%]!+day
if %yearMOD4% equ 0 if %month% gtr 2 set /A dayOfYear+=1

echo %dayOfYear%
```

**Note:** This relies on the date format `MM/DD/YYYY`.

**EDIT 2020/08/10**: *Better method added*

I modified the method so it now uses `wmic` to get the date. The new method is also shorten, but no simpler! **`;)`**:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "daysPerMonth=0 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30"

for /F "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year') do (
   set /A "dayOfYear=%%a, month=%%b, leap=!(%%c%%4)*(((month-3)>>31)+1)" 2>NUL
)
set /A "i=1, dayOfYear+=%daysPerMonth: =+(((month-(i+=1))>>31)+1)*%+leap"

echo %dayOfYear%
```

Comment: I added a note concerning dependency of your approach on system date format. To retrieve the system date in a standardised format, the output of `wmic OS GET LocalDateTime` could be parsed.

Comment: what's the purpose of prefixing the 2-places numbers with `1` and subtracting `100`afterwards, like in `set /A month=1%Date:~0,2%-100`?

Comment: just found out myself: `set /A` interpretes numbers starting with `0` as octal ones, like month `07` or `08`; the latter is an invalid octal number; prefixing with `1` makes it a valid decimal number `108`, subtracting `100` results in `8`...

Comment: @Aacini Is there also a way to do this in bash on linux?

Answer (score 2):

@Aacini's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31569171/5047996) has got two weak points (although it suffices for many applications, and it is a great approach after all!):

1. the retrieved system date relies on format `MM/DD/YYYY`, but `%Date%` is locale-dependent;
2. the calculation does not fully comply with the definition of leap years (see [this article](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html));

The following is a revised version of @Aacini's batch script (described within explanatory remarks):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A i=0, sum=0
rem accumulate day-offsets for every month in %accum[1...12]%
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set /A accum[!i!]=sum, sum+=%%a
)
rem check for availability of alternative date value given via (1st) command line argument,
rem just for convenient batch testing
if "%1"=="" (
    rem WMIC retrieves current system date/time in standardised format;
    rem parse its output by FOR /F, then store it in %CurrDate%
    for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%D in ('wmic OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE ^| find "="') do (
        set CurrDate=%%D
    )
) else (
    rem apply date value from command line in YYYYMMDD format (not checked for validity)
    set CurrDate=%1
)
rem extract %month% and %day%; 
set /A month=1%CurrDate:~4,2%-100, day=1%CurrDate:~6,2%-100
rem compute several moduli needed for determining whether year is leap year
set /A yearMOD4=%CurrDate:~0,4% %% 4
set /A yearMOD100=%CurrDate:~0,4% %% 100, yearMOD400=%CurrDate:~0,4% %% 400
rem calculate %dayOfYear% as it were not a leap year
set /A dayOfYear=!accum[%month%]!+day
rem adapt %dayOfYear% only in case %month% is past February (29th)
if %month% gtr 2 (
    rem check for leap year and adapt %dayOfYear% accordingly
    if %yearMOD4% equ 0 set /A dayOfYear+=1
    if %yearMOD400% neq 0 if %yearMOD100% equ 0 set /A dayOfYear-=1
)
rem compound statement to let %dayOfYear% survive SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL block
endlocal & set dayOfYear=%dayOfYear%
rem return result
echo %dayOfYear%
```

Comment: rationale for posting a separate answer rather than editing [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31569171/5047996): reference http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291705/5047996

Comment: You are right: my method to calculate the day of year will fail on March/2100, but don't worry: I scheduled a reminder to take place on January/2100 so I will post the required modifications here and an advice for the OP to implement they. This way, the OP will save a lot of computer time avoiding to execute useless operations for the next 85 years!  **`;)`**

Comment: Great, thanks! ;-) The most recent year where your implementation failed was 1900 -- but I know, computers were not that common back then... For the question at hand where the current date is of interest only, the deviation is not relevant  of course; however, for other dates it might become an issue...

Comment: Works great in Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition. Returns the same, correct, day of year for both calls, with and without YYYYMMDD input argument.

Answer (score 1):

This use the **<kbd>`laps years`</kbd>** in editable in loop **| <kbd>`for /l %%L in (2020 4 2100)`</kbd> |** **< or more!**

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && set "_cmd=Get Day^,Month^,Year^" 
for /l %%L in (2020 4 2100)do set "_array_leap_year_=!_array_leap_year_!%%L,"
for /f "tokens=1-3delims= " %%a in ('wmic Path Win32_LocalTime !_cmd! ^| findstr /r "[0-9]"')do (
set "_yy=%%c" & set "_mm=0%%b" & set "_dd=0%%a" && set "_mm=!_mm:~-2!" & set "_dd=!_dd:~-2!" & set _date=!_yy!_!_mm!_!_dd!)
echo/!_array_leap_year_!|findstr /lic:"!_date:~0,4!," >nul&&(set "_leap_=29" & set "_year_=366")||(set "_leap_=28" & set "_year_=365")
set "_mm_dd_year_=01-31,02-!_leap_!,03-31,04-30,05-31,06-30,07-31,08-31,09-30,10-31,11-30,12-31" && set /a "_cnt=0" & set /a "_loop=!_mm! * 6" 
(for /l %%d in (0 6 !_loop!)do set "_sum=!_mm_dd_year_:~%%d,5!" & if "9!_sum:~,2!" lss "9!_mm!" set /a "_day_year_+=!_sum:~-2!") 
set /a "_day_year_+=!_dd!" && set /a "_remain=!_day_year_! - !_year_!" && echo/Today: !_date! ^| Day of Year: !_day_year_! ^| Days Remaining: !_remain:-=!
```

---

> **|** **Result** **|**  **<kbd>`Today: 2019_04_21 | Day of Year: 111 | Days Remaining: 254`</kbd>**

---

Conventional formatting:

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_cmd=Get Day^,Month^,Year^"
for /l %%L in (2020 4 2100)do set "_array_leap_year_=!_array_leap_year_!%%L,"


for /f "tokens=1-3delims= " %%a in ('wmic Path Win32_LocalTime !_cmd! ^| findstr /r "[0-9]"')do (
    set "_yy=%%c"
    set "_mm=0%%b"
    set "_dd=0%%a"
    set "_mm=!_mm:~-2!"
    set "_dd=!_dd:~-2!"
    set _date=!_yy!_!_mm!_!_dd!
    )

    echo/!_array_leap_year_!|findstr /lic:"!_date:~0,4!," >nul && (
    set "_leap_=29" & set "_year_=366" )||( set "_leap_=28" & set "_year_=365" )

    set "_mm_dd_year_=01-31,02-!_leap_!,03-31,04-30,05-31,06-30,07-31,08-31,09-30,10-31,11-30,12-31"
    set /a "_loop=!_mm! * 6"

    for /l %%d in (0 6 !_loop!)do set "_sum=!_mm_dd_year_:~%%d,5!" && (
    if "9!_sum:~,2!" lss "9!_mm!" set /a "_day_year_+=!_sum:~-2!"  )

    set /a "_day_year_+=!_dd!"
    set /a "_remain=!_day_year_! - !_year_!"
    echo/Today: !_date! ^| Day of Year: !_day_year_! ^| Days Remaining: !_remain:-=!
```