# Batch file to compare input date with sysdate

Tags: file, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file to read input.txt date and compare the date with yesterday's date. If it matches and the last line=EOF then execute my java program. So far I have got bellow.

```
ECHO OFF
set "firstLine="
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do (
  If not defined firstLine set "firstLine=%%A"
  set Lastline=%%A
)
REM *** FIRST CHECK ***
if "EOF" NEQ "%Lastline%" goto :fail

call :extractDate firstLineDate firstLine 
call :convertToJulianDay julianFirstLine firstLineDate
set "today=%date%"
call :convertToJulianDay julianToday today


set /a diff=julianToday-julianFirstLine
REM *** SECOND CHECK ***
if %diff% NEQ 1 goto :fail
exit /b

:fail
echo File doesn't fit
```

Please note that if conditions are matching going to java program is not written here. But I only need to compare two dates and the date difference is -1 then execute my program, which I have already taken care of.

Bellow is the input.txt file contents.

```
AML.DATA|01-JUN-2016
PORT_DATA|560538
NDB_AML_AA|43063
NDB_AML_LD|12878
NDB_AML_REPO|496
NDB_AML_TRAN|84596
NDB_AML_JOINT_AC|219873
NDB_AML_CUS_REL_PRTY|43
NDB_AML_BICCODE|108292
CUSTOMER_MASTER|684124
CATEGORY.MASTER|3288
DEPT.MASTER|2527
COUNTRY.MASTER|251
CUSTOMER.STATUS.MASTER|26
INDUSTRY.MASTER|65
JOB.TITLE.MASTER|22
COMPANY.MASTER|121
TRANSACTION.MASTER|3133
RELATION.MASTER|56
NDB_AML_TBILL_TBOND|2845
EOF
```

Comment: If you let me share a useless unproductive comment (well... hard work is not everything in life), you are very brave just for using Windows batch to manipulate delimited text files. I take my hat off to you.

Comment: And where is your question? Your script logic looks fine.  Or do you expect that somebody will write `:extractDate` and `:convertToJulianDay` subroutines for you?

Comment: @JosefZ My logic is okay, but I'm looking for some help on how to write the sub routines.

Comment: See e.g. [Aacini's DATETOJULIAN.BAT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11213142/3439404). I think that it's exactly your `:convertToJulianDay` subroutine…