# Subtract a number of years from a date in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I currently have this:

```
 for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS  GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "FileNameDate=%%I"
 set "FileNameDate=%FileNameDate:~0,4%-%FileNameDate:~4,2%-%FileNameDate:~6,2%"
```

It is used to get a date in a format that matches the format of dates on files that another batch file uses to find past dates. I want to use this again, but I want to alter the date by subtracting 2 years from it. So instead of outputting:

2018-11-29

I'd like to get:

2016-11-29

Understand?

How can I do that?

Comment: You might want to review https://stackoverflow.com/a/11213142/864696

Comment: Before you add the hyphens, grab the first 8 numbers from the variable and subtract 20,000 from it. Of course that won't help you with leap years.

Comment: I have looked at that. I don't think I have the level of understanding of this code to make much use of it. My experience and skill level with this type of code is very low.

Comment: @BenHolman if you thought it would be simple like it is with modern day programming languages you are sadly mistaken. Doing date math in pure batch requires the algorithims you see in those links.

Comment: @Squashman. Thanks. I was hoping for easy. You have cured me of my disillusions.

Comment: If you want easy then you call out to powershell.  This technique has also been covered dozens of times as well on StackOverFlow.  Not very hard to search and find an answer here. `For /F "delims=" %%G In ('PowerShell -Command "&{((Get-Date).AddYears(-2)).ToString('yyyyMMdd')}"') Do set fdate=%%G`

Comment: @RossPresser: The method given at your link don't works in this case because it is based on number of _days_. How many days should be used to subtract two years: 730 or 731?

Comment: @Aacini good point. And good thing I didn't propose an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple via a Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS  GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "FileNameDate=%%I"
set "FileNameDate=%FileNameDate:~0,8%"

REM Activate next line for test:
REM set /P "FileNameDate=YYYYMMDD: "

set /A "FileNameDate-=20000+!(1%FileNameDate:~4,4%-10229)"
set "FileNameDate=%FileNameDate:~0,4%-%FileNameDate:~4,2%-%FileNameDate:~6,2%"
echo %FileNameDate%
```

Test output:

```
YYYYMMDD: 20181129
2016-11-29

YYYYMMDD: 20160229
2014-02-28
```

Comment: That's awesome! As I said above. I'm VERY inexperienced with batch script. Can you explain how you did that? Or point me to something that does? Thanks!