# Is it possible to perform a mathematical calculation using a DOS echo, in a single line?

Tags: dos

For example, can I do

`echo 3 + 5`

and get `8`?

Is it possible to do calculations using the date?

Comment: For date arithmetic, try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355425/date-arithmetic-in-dos-scripting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `set /a` to calculate a mathematical expression:

```
set /a x=3+5
echo %x%
```

Edit: here's a one-liner:

```
@for /f usebackq %i in (`set /a 3 + 5`) do @echo %i
```

Comment: From the title: `in a single line`. Also, using `set /a 3 + 5` to echo the result assumes that the user hasn't used `@ECHO OFF` at the start of the batch file, which is pretty customary.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'll see what else I can come up with.

Comment: No need to use FOR: `cmd /c set /a 3+5`

Answer (score 3):

For the first question you can do it in a single line by using the & to chain the commands.

```
set /a x=3+5 & echo %x%
```

At least this works in [windows7](/questions/tagged/windows7)