# Subtract days in batch file

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, cmd

I'll try to subtract 60 days of the date of today but I don't know how I can do that.

I've my date like this :

```
@echo off
pause

SET currentYear=%date:~9,4%
ECHO %currentYear%
SET month=%date:~6,2%
ECHO %month%
SET day=%date:~3,2%
SET date=%day%%month%%currentYear%

ECHO %day%
ECHO %date%

pause
```

I've look across internet but I don't find something simple and useful!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date arithmetic in dos scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355425/date-arithmetic-in-dos-scripting)

Comment: Do not try to set system environment variables.  Specifically, use `SET sys_date=%day%%month%%currentYear%` instead of `SET date=%day%%month%%currentYear%`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get 3 days past date from current date Using Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191084/how-to-get-3-days-past-date-from-current-date-using-batch-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

Call :GetDateTime Year Month Day
Echo %Year% %Month% %Day%
Call :SubtractDate %Year% %Month% %Day% -60 Ret
echo %Ret%
exit /b


:SubtractDate Year Month Day <+/-Days> Ret
::Adapted from DosTips Functions::
setlocal & set a=%4
set "yy=%~1"&set "mm=%~2"&set "dd=%~3"
set /a "yy=10000%yy% %%10000,mm=100%mm% %% 100,dd=100%dd% %% 100"
if %yy% LSS 100 set /a yy+=2000 &rem Adds 2000 to two digit years
set /a JD=dd-32075+1461*(yy+4800+(mm-14)/12)/4+367*(mm-2-(mm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((yy+4900+(mm-14)/12)/100)/4
if %a:~0,1% equ + (set /a JD=%JD%+%a:~1%) else set /a JD=%JD%-%a:~1%
set /a L= %JD%+68569,     N= 4*L/146097, L= L-(146097*N+3)/4, I= 4000*(L+1)/1461001
set /a L= L-1461*I/4+31, J= 80*L/2447,  K= L-2447*J/80,      L= J/11
set /a J= J+2-12*L,      I= 100*(N-49)+I+L
set /a YYYY= I, MM=100+J, DD=100+K
set MM=%MM:~-2% & set DD=%DD:~-2%
set ret=%MM: =%/%DD: =%/%YYYY: =%
endlocal & set %~5=%ret%
exit /b

:GetDateTime Year Month Day Hour Minute Second
@echo off & setlocal
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
( ENDLOCAL
     IF "%~1" NEQ "" set "%~1=%YYYY%" 
     IF "%~2" NEQ "" set "%~2=%MM%" 
     IF "%~3" NEQ "" set "%~3=%DD%"
     IF "%~4" NEQ "" set "%~4=%HH%" 
     IF "%~5" NEQ "" set "%~5=%Min%"
     IF "%~6" NEQ "" set "%~6=%Sec%"
)
exit /b
```

Comment: I just change this : for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
( ENDLOCAL
     IF "%~1" NEQ "" set "%~1=%YYYY%" 
     IF "%~2" NEQ "" set "%~2=%MM%" 
     IF "%~3" NEQ "" set "%~3=%DD%"
)
exit /b

Comment: @MattWilliamson I am getting `1JDa:~1JDa:~1 was unexpected at this time.` when running this, probably from this line: `if %a:~0,1% equ + (set /a JD=%JD%+%a:~1%) else set /a JD=%JD%-%a:~1%`. I can't figure out how to get rid of the warning. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general purpose batch file that is robust - it can be reduced to 8 lines or so if you want to include it in another batch file.

You would use something like: `datetime.bat today -60`

```
:: Date forward & backward
@echo off
if "%~2"=="" (
echo to get todays date use         call "%~n0" today 0
echo to get yesterdays date use     call "%~n0" today -1
echo to get 25 days before 19441213 call "%~n0" 1944/12/13 -25
echo to get 1250 days in the future call "%~n0" today 1250
echo.
echo Add a third parameter if you want a separator in the date string
echo EG: for this format YYYY-MM-DD using today's date
echo     call "%~n0" today 0 -
echo.
pause
goto :EOF)

set date1=%1
set qty=%2
set separator=%~3
if /i "%date1%" EQU "TODAY" (set date1=now) else (set date1="%date1%")
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%qty%,%date1%)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+month(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         right(100+day(s),2)^&_
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"         d
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set result=%%a
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
endlocal& (
set "YY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "daynum=%result:~-1%"
)
if %daynum% EQU 1 set "weekday=Sunday"
if %daynum% EQU 2 set "weekday=Monday"
if %daynum% EQU 3 set "weekday=Tuesday"
if %daynum% EQU 4 set "weekday=Wednesday"
if %daynum% EQU 5 set "weekday=Thursday"
if %daynum% EQU 6 set "weekday=Friday"
if %daynum% EQU 7 set "weekday=Saturday"

set "day=%YY%%separator%%MM%%separator%%DD%"
echo %%day%% is set to "%day%" (without the quotes)
echo %%YY%% is set to %YY%
echo %%MM%% is set to %MM%
echo %%DD%% is set to %DD%
echo The weekday turns out to be: %weekday%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done also with a jscript code embedded into cmd script:

Here's the `dayM.bat` that accepts only one argument - the days you want to add to the current date and prints the result:

```
  @if (@X) == (@Y) @end /* JScript comment 
    @echo off   
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
    exit /b %errorlevel%       
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var days=parseInt(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));


Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

var date = new Date();

WScript.Echo(date.addDays(5));
WScript.Echo("Year: " + date.getFullYear());
WScript.Echo("Month: " + date.getMonth());
WScript.Echo("DayOfTeWEek: " + date.getDay());
```

examaple:

```
E:\scripts>dayM.bat 7
Sun Nov 8 16:27:48 UTC+0200 2020
Year: 2020
Month: 10
DayOfTeWEek: 2
DayOfTheMonth: 3
```

You can modify it in way that will be suitable for you.