# subtracting date in bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get a start date and an end date. The start and end data should vary by 1 full day. I am having issue subtracting or adding from either the start or end date. How can I go about doing this? I have attempted `-%1%` and `+%1%`.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"

set /a y=%dt:~0,4%
set /a m=1%dt:~4,2%
set /a d=1%dt:~6,2%


set subdate=%y%%m:~-2%%d:~-2%

SET START_DATE= %subdate:~0,4%/%subdate:~4,2%/%subdate:~6,2% 00:00 AM
SET END_DATE = %dt:~0,4%/%dt:~4,2%/%dt:~6,2%+%1% 00:00 AM

echo %start_date%
echo %end_date%
echo done
```

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47800795/1417694) from yesterday.  You can add or subtract with this function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any easy way to get 2 days ago date using batch scripting CDM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800605/is-there-any-easy-way-to-get-2-days-ago-date-using-batch-scripting-cdm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to get start date to be yesterday and end date to be today. If I misunderstand what you are seeking, please say so.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%t IN (`powershell -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')"`) DO (SET "START_DATE=%%t")
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%t IN (`powershell -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Date).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')"`) DO (SET "END_DATE=%%t")

echo %START_DATE%
echo %END_DATE%
```

Comment: I changed MM to mm in the minutes part of the string.