# Subtraction of a number from a variable in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, subtraction

I'm new to batch scripting, so please be lenient with this question. When I'm subtracting 1 from 'TodayDay' variable, the value is not getting updated. Below is the line.

```
set /a "TodayDay=%TodayDay%-1"
```

My use case is to find if today's date is less than the 'lastOpenedDate' variable, I want to set the 'lastOpenedDate' to yesterday's

```
set lastOpenedDate=2017-12-22
IF %TodayYear%-%TodayMonth%-%TodayDay% LSS %lastOpenedDate% (   
  echo Before Subtraction TodayDay is %TodayDay%
  set /a "TodayDay=%TodayDay%-1"
  echo After Subtraction TodayDay is %TodayDay%
)
```

When I ran the above code, The output is:

```
Before Subtraction TodayDay is 20
After Subtraction TodayDay is 20
```

I got the other variable values from the below-mentioned code

```
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%F in ('
    wmic PATH Win32_LocalTime GET Day^,Month^,Year /FORMAT:TABLE
') do (
    for /F "tokens=1-3" %%L in ("%%F") do (
        set TodayDay=0%%L
        set TodayMonth=0%%M
        set TodayYear=%%N
    )
)
set TodayDay=%TodayDay:~-2%
set TodayMonth=%TodayMonth:~-2%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In Batch files all variables are STRINGS.  It knows nothing of DATES or INT, or insert any other variable type here.  If you need to do date math you need to change the date to the julian date and then subtract from it.  I think I have answered this question twice in the past two weeks.  Please search StackOverFlow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any easy way to get 2 days ago date using batch scripting CDM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800605/is-there-any-easy-way-to-get-2-days-ago-date-using-batch-scripting-cdm)

Comment: @Squashman, I agree. But, the 'TodayDay' variable has 20 as it's value. When I'm trying to subtract 1 from 20 why it isn't returning 19?

Comment: Your code as too many flaws and caveats to explain.  Even the answer Magoo gave you below will still fail.  If you need to do date math correctly your options are to use the Julian date with Batch-Files or call out to Powershell.

Comment: @Squashman, Answer gave by Magoo is working as expected. Thanks for your views on this.

Comment: Your code only works in specific situations.  See my comment on Magoo's code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to search SO using the top bar for `delayed expansion`. It's #1 FAQ.

change

```
  set /a "TodayDay=%TodayDay%-1"
  echo After Subtraction TodayDay is %TodayDay%
)
```

to

```
  set /a "TodayDay=%TodayDay%-1"
)
echo After Subtraction TodayDay is %TodayDay%
```

which will make sense once you familiarise yourself with `delayed expansion.`

Now the next problem you'll run into (which won't show itself until the 8th or 9th of the month) is that in batch a leading `0` means "octal" so - you actually need

```
  set /a "TodayDay=1%TodayDay%-1"
)
set "TodayDay=%TodayDay:~-2"
echo After Subtraction TodayDay is %TodayDay%
```

which adds 100 to the day number by stringing the `1` in front of the day number, then you need to get the last 2 characters.

Comment: @Shashank, this code will not work on Leap Days or when you subtract back to a new month. If the date is 2017-12-01 and you subtract 1 from the day it will not give you 30 as that is the last day of November.  On March 1st, 2020, it will not give you 29 for the month of February.

Comment: @Squashman, I agree. My use case doesn't require to get dates mentioned by you. For 2017-12-01, I'll get 0 as the day and I'm fine with that. Anyways the solution shared by you is the best. But, for my use case, I'm good with the above solution.

Comment: Thanks bud ; the most simplest solution ; saw some 40+ lines of code answers out there. This worked; still relevant while punching out Tableau files via command line x bat