# Batch - Get the date from 8 days from now

Tags: date, batch-file

I'm trying to get the date from 8 days from now to navigate in a tree structure.

I've use this but I got a problem at the start of the new month (I got a negative number and thats logical) :

```
set annee=%date:~6,4%
set mois=%date:~3,2%
set jour=%date:~0,2%
set /a j8=%jour%-8

cd %annee%\%mois%\%j8%
```

Got you a solution to resolve my problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19990367/12343998), for one of many existing solutions to this often asked question type, then please delete this duplicate question

Comment: @T3RR0R Thanks a lot ! I'havent well express my research ...
I got a question about the script. I don't realy understand how it works and how can I use it :/

Comment: the usage requirements are explained at the start of the script. Call the script with 2 arguments. Arg 1: current date Arg 2: integer value for the offset value. The calculation of the date offset is done using a vbs script created by the batch using the values passed as args

Comment: Ok thanks. It doesnt work for me but I think I did something wrong (I'm not that good at batch scripting). I will test some things.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be with a polyglot script that embeds jscript.
Here's the `dayAdder.bat` that accepts only one argument - the days you want to add to the current date and prints the result:

```
  @if (@X) == (@Y) @end /* JScript comment 
    @echo off   
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
    exit /b %errorlevel%       
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var days=parseInt(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));


Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

var date = new Date();

WScript.Echo(date.addDays(5));
WScript.Echo("Year: " + date.getFullYear());
WScript.Echo("Month: " + date.getMonth());
WScript.Echo("DayOfTeWEek: " + date.getDay());
```

examaple:

```
E:\scripts>dayAdder.bat 7
Sun Nov 8 16:27:48 UTC+0200 2020
Year: 2020
Month: 10
DayOfTeWEek: 2
DayOfTheMonth: 3
```

You can modify it in way that will be suitable for you.