# date subtraction in cmd

Tags: date, cmd, subtraction

I have a date format in 26-Aug-2016 style. I want to subtract 10days from this date. This date is not necessary to be today. It can be any date with this format only.

For example:
Input: 26-Aug-2016;
Days Subtract: 10;
Output: 16-Aug-2016

Another example:
Input: 26-Aug-2016;
Days Subtract: 30;
Output: 27-Jul-2016.

Thanks Andre for telling me how Stackoverflow works.  I am new to this.

I have tried this but the problem is that it will not go to the previous month. Basically i have split the date and subtracted day.

```
set nth=1
for /F "tokens=%nth% delims=-" %%a in ("24-Aug-2016") do set 

nthstring=%%a

echo today is %nthstring%

set /a dd=%nthstring%-30:~0,2%

echo previous is %dd%
pause
pause
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('date /t') do set thedate=%%i
set mm=%thedate:~3,3%
REM set dd=%thedate:~0,2%
set yyyy=%thedate:~6,5%


set backdate=%dd%-%mm%%yyyy%
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is to help you not to do your work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date arithmetic in cmd scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355425/date-arithmetic-in-cmd-scripting)