# Sqlcmd Subtract date

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I have created the following batch file to run a query, and save the results in a .csv file.

```
sqlcmd -S MyLogin -i LocationToSql -E -o "C:\Users\user\Desktop\query result\result2-%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%.csv" -s";" -w 700
```

Right now, i'm saving the result as: **result2-2017-06-21.csv**
However, i would like it to be: **result2-2017-06-20.csv**

But i don't know how to subtract 1 day of the command.
The date is defined like:

```
%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%
```

Comment: Also if people downvote, please tell me why...

Comment: [This post may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355425/date-arithmetic-in-cmd-scripting)

Comment: Most probably because of lack of own research/efforts -- see this: [ask]

Comment: You could borrow date arithmetic functions from another language, like PowerShell, VBScript, JavaScript, which are all native to modern Windows systems; the Windows command prompt and batch files are not capable of such...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly modified a script I recently posted here:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set day=%date:~-10,2%
set month=%date:~-7,2%
set year=%date:~-4,4%

echo.%day%|findstr /r /b "0">nul&&set day=%day:~1%
echo.%month%|findstr /r /b "0">nul&&set month=%month:~1%
set /a day-=1
if %day% lss 1 (
    set /a day+=30
    set /a month-=1
    if !month!==2 (set /a day-=2
                   set /a leap=year%%4
                   if !leap!==0 set day+=1
    )
    for /l %%# in (1 2 7) do if %month%==%%# set /a day+=1
    for %%# in (8 10 12) do if %month%==%%# set /a day+=1
    if !month!==0 (
        set month=12
        set /a year-=1
    )
)
set day=0%day%
set month=0%month%

echo %year%-%month:~-2%-%day:~-2%
```

This will echo the date of yesterday in YYYY-MM-DD format. You can also edit the line with `set /a day-=1` to subtract mutliple days.